# How to fix Arabic/Persian text and font in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this piece of code right here:

```
import pygame
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
font = pygame.font.Font('./arial.ttf', 10)
text = font.render('سلام', True, (255, 255, 255))

win.fill((0, 0, 0))
win.blit(text, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

for i in range(5):
    pygame.event.clear()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

What I expect: `سلام`
What I get: `س‌ل‎ا‌م`
How to fix it? (I don't care if I need to use another library to fix it, But I must use pygame for rest of code)
I also tried it on both pygame 1.9.6 and 2.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use arabic_reshaper library.

```
pip install arabic-reshaper
```

Refer to this https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper

You will need python-bidi as well

```
pip install python-bidi
```

You can do it as follow

```
import pygame
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
font = pygame.font.Font('arial.ttf', 10)
text_to_be_reshaped = 'اللغة العربية رائعة'
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
print(reshaped_text)
text = font.render(bidi_text, True, (255, 255, 255))



win.fill((0, 0, 0))
win.blit(text, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

for i in range(5):
    pygame.event.clear()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible to while still keeping the font rendering within pygame, with the modern fork of pygame, pygame-ce (pygame community edition)

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
# replace with your path to Arial
font = pygame.font.Font("C:\\windows\\Fonts\\ARIAL.TTF", 80)

# New text shaping and text direction support in pygame-ce 2.1.4
font.set_script("Arab")
font.set_direction(pygame.DIRECTION_RTL)

text = font.render('سلام', True, "white")

win.fill("black")
win.blit(text, (10, 10))
pygame.display.update()

for i in range(5):
    pygame.event.clear()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

[image: Rendered output text]

Pygame-ce is a drop in replacement for pygame, just `pip uninstall pygame` and `pip install pygame-ce` to get advantage of its new features. (Both can't be installed at the same time, because they both import as pygame)